# MDX Step By Step Book

Tags: mdx

Am trying to learn MDX using book called "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 MDX Step by step", and i downloaded the samples databases for the book , but when trying to attach the database it gives me an error "Access denied" , I'm trying to attach the database to SQL Server 2008 R2, 
will it make a difference to attach it to R2 as the book tutorial and samples is for 2008 only ??, 
Note that i searched for the error and it said that i had to delete also the log file that is downloaded with the samples database, i did that also but nothing worked

Please help

Comment: There is not nearly enough information here to help you. Are you trying to attach a SQL database, or an SSAS database? Do you have SQL2008R2 installed locally or on a development server? Do you have admin permissions to the box? To the services? Too many questions to ask.

Comment: Have you tried what i have proposed?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error several times. It has nothing to do with your version, i have done it on both SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2012. It´s because of some denied access to the folders where you downloaded and installed the MDX-stuff. One way to solve it is to copy the "MdxStepByStep.mdf" & "MdxStepBySteplog" files to your data-folder where the other databases lies. My path is for example:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11\MSSQL\DATA".
```

Then you just change the script´s path to:

```
exec master..sp_attach_db
'MdxStepByStep',
'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11\MSSQL\DATA\MdxStepByStep.mdf'
```

Do not copy the "MdxStepByStep_log" because then you will get an error that the file already exists.
It should work, also there should not be any problem with the analysis cube if i remember correctly, tell me if there is and i will look into it.